# Unique linear combination in matrix with column sum $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that the numbers in each column sum to $0$, and all diagonal entries are non-zero. So, $A$ is non-invertible, and some linear combination of columns is equal to the $\textbf{0}$ vector. Is the linear combination necessarily unique (up to constant factor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0&0 \\
-1&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1 \\
0&0&-1&1 \end{pmatrix},$$
which very clearly has 2-dimensional kernel. So the answer is no, it is not necessary.